# Sql Server 2014 showing no services in the configuration manager after install?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using Windows 8. Recently I downloaded sql server management studio 2014 from the official website. But when I open the Sql server 2014 Configuration Manager there are **no** services listed.

During installation, there were no any errors.

[image: config manager]

I did search everywhere but still I didn't find anything, please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand .. I'm new in `SQL server`

Comment: @Tanner What's NSFW? or better I don't know?

Comment: Ah ok, I had a look, it's safe actually.

Comment: no issue now, @Jeroen has edited it into question.

Comment: Could anyone please help me? :(

Comment: @rajivmishra any previous sql installation son the box?

Comment: No, there were no any `son` there before installation :(

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299, make sure you use SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe or SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe. SQLManagementStudio_x86_FRA.exe doesn't contain a database engine.

Comment: I downloaded `Sql server management studio 2014` from here.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx

Comment: And you are sure you picked a version that has a database included with it?

Comment: In this [WEBSITE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx) I could see `localDB`!..

Comment: Inside `win+r` as i type `services.msc` I'm unable to see any sql or service into it..

Comment: If you picked that one it should work, however there are also options on that site that are just tools without any database. Is there any chance you could try deleting the installation and install one of the 2 exe's I just send you?

Comment: Okay!.. send me the links

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and make sure to download either SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe or SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe! I downloaded my sql server 2014 there and it works fine :)

Comment: unitl it download i would like to ask .. should i need to turn ON all windows updates and Firewall during sql programming?

Comment: To be honest I don't know if it is required, I can tell you however that I have windows updates and Firewall both ON and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I'm just checking pls w8.. I would accept your as it works.. i'm sorry .. i'll accept your answer as it works today :)

Comment: No problem mate, didn't ask for the accept of the answer. I'm just intrested to know if your problem is fixed :D

Comment: :D ... I'm install Visual studio at the time i guess, All problem is about Visual Studio.. Because i found Visual studio comes along with database engine .. if  i do not mistake!

Comment: Visual Studio indeed comes with a DataBase. However I'm surprised that this gives a conflict. Since I never expierenced any propblems with this

Comment: And how is your problem going? Is it fixed?

Comment: Hmm.. there should be another solution. Can you completely remove the sql servers? Reboot and try reinstalling them?

Comment: Okay thanks.. I'm reinstalling this again,.. Again thanks for supporting me.. :)

Comment: No problem :). How is it going? Is your problem fixed now?